# Swift - Accesing UITextView from DetailViewController

Tags: ios, swift, scope, uitextview

I have been working on a new app recently, and I have been having this wierd problem. Everytime I try and access my  textviews.text property outside of viewdidload I get the error "Instance member 'detailDescriptionLabel' (my textview) cannot be used on type 'DetailViewController'(the class I am in)" I would really apreciate your help. Thanks.

The code where the error comes up:

```
var updated: String = detailDescriptionLabel.text {
    didSet {

        if updated != oldValue {
            textFieldDidChange()
        }

    }
}
```

The whole entire class, which controls the cells on a table (just incase):

```
var start : CGPoint?

var red : CGFloat = 0.0
var green : CGFloat = 0.0
var blue : CGFloat = 0.0


@IBAction func erase(sender: AnyObject) {
    red = 1
    green = 1
    blue = 1
}

@IBAction func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.imageView.image = nil
}


@IBAction func blackPen(sender: AnyObject) {
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 0
}

@IBAction func redPen(sender: AnyObject) {
    red = 1
    green = 0
    blue = 0
}

@IBAction func bluePen(sender: AnyObject) {
    red = 0
    green = 0
    blue = 1
}

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

let notes = PFObject(className: "Notes")



var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {

}


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.configureView()

}




var updated: String = detailDescriptionLabel.text {
    didSet {
        if updated != oldValue {
            textFieldDidChange()
        }

    }
}


func textFieldDidChange() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Notes")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Content") { (notes, error) -> Void in

        notes!["Content"] = self.detailDescriptionLabel.text
        print("Updated")


    }
}


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let newText = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! String
    print(newText)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func draw(start : CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    imageView?.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.width, height: imageView.frame.height))
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
   //Define starting point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y)
    //Define end point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y)
    //Close the path between the starting and ending point (draw)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    imageView.image = newImage
}

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let Touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    start = Touch.locationInView(self.imageView)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let Touch = touches.first as UITouch?
    let end = Touch?.locationInView(self.imageView)
    if let s = self.start {
        draw(s, end: end!)
    }
    self.start = end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString: String {
    didSet {
        if newValue  != oldValue {
            //what ever you wanna do here.
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code. There is also a "newValue" that can used.

Like I said, use this code to update when ever UITextView.text changes text.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    myString = (textView.text+text)
    return true
}
```

Comment: The problem still persists that whenever I mention detailDescriptionLabel.text outside viewdidload, the error comes up. Thanks though.

Comment: Can I see a bit more of your code, like the "detailDescriptionLabel" declaration the class declaration etc.

Comment: I have added the whole entire class in my question above. Thanks.

Comment: Does it show the same error message when you try to access the text view from any other method e.g.  configureView ?

Comment: Just in case... if your actual goal is to track if the text view text was modified... you can connect your 'textViewChanged' method to the text view from story board

Comment: @luckystars The error does not come up when I access the textview from configureView, however it does everytime I access it outside a method eg. creating a global variable such as "var textview = detailDescriptionLabel.text"

Answer (score 0):

It seems setting a member variable in this way is not allowed... you will need to implement the textViewDidChange delegate method